# Using OpenMP in Visual Studio 2012 -> the code gets even slower than without

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, openmp

I'm trying to use OpenMP in my project in Visual Studio 2012 for acceleration of some for-loops, but I'm observing some strange behaviour. OpenMP does not improve the performance, it even leads to slower runtimes...

I've created the following simple demo with OpenMP:

```html
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

#include <omp.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  // get the number of processors in this system
  int iCPU = omp_get_num_procs();

  std::cout << "Number of processors: " << iCPU << std::endl;

  int n_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
  std::cout << "Number of threads (before): " << n_threads << std::endl;

//#pragma omp parallel
  // set the number of threads
  omp_set_num_threads(/*iCPU*/5);

#pragma omp parallel
  n_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
  std::cout << "Number of threads (after): " << n_threads << std::endl;

  const int length = 10000000;

  unsigned short *pSrc = new unsigned short[length];
  unsigned short *pDst = new unsigned short[length];

  memset(pSrc, '\0', length*sizeof(unsigned short));

  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    *(pSrc + i) = (unsigned short)(((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX)*255);

  int n = 20;
  double time_acc = 0.0;

  for (int ind = 0; ind < n; ++ind)
  {
    memset(pDst, '\0', length*sizeof(unsigned short));

    double stime = omp_get_wtime();

    int i;

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
      //std::cout << "thread: " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
      *(pDst + i) = *(pSrc + i) + *(pSrc + i);
    }

    double etime = omp_get_wtime();
    double elapsed = etime - stime;

    std::cout << "elapsed = " << elapsed*1e3 << " [ms]"<< std::endl;

    time_acc += elapsed*1e3;
  }

  std::cout << "Runtime (averaged) = " << time_acc/n << " [ms]"<< std::endl;

  delete[] pSrc;
  delete[] pDst;

  std::cout << "Press any button to exit" << std::endl;
  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

OpenMP support in Visual Studio settings is activated. Running this code multiple times without and with OpenMP I observe the following behaviour:

1. Sometimes runtimes are more or less equal;
2. But very often usage of OpenMP slows down the computation...

Does anybody have any idea what is going on here? I have 8 cores CPU i7-3720QM. Setting the number of threads seems to work fine and 'omp_get_thread_num()' prints the actual thread number...

Any advice is kindly appreciated!

Best,
Alexey

Comment: Use larger chunks.  Right now the overhead of managing 10000000 separate steps is outweighing the benefit of using more cores.  Not to mention the false cache sharing. Try say 1000 chunks of 10000 byte copies each.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do you mean something like this:

    for (index = 0; index < chunk_n; ++index)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < chunk_size; ++i)
        *(pDst + index*chunk_size + i) = *(pSrc + index*chunk_size + i) + *(pSrc + index*chunk_size + i);
    }                                                                                                         How shall I accelerate it with OpenMP:

#pragma omp parallel for private(index)                                                           And what do you mean by a false cache sharing in this case? Thanks!